# convert TextField to Var Int (swift)

Tags: swift, int, textfield

Hi Im new to swift programming. I would like to get the input of a textfield, convert it to an int and then work with that int (decreasing it). Here is my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var minutes: UITextField!

 @IBOutlet weak var seconds: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var label_Timer: UILabel!

@IBAction func btn_Timer(_ sender: UITextField) {

    var min:Int = Int(minutes.text!)
    var sec:Int = Int(seconds.text!)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerRunning), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func timerRunning(){

    sec -= 1

//operate on min and sec here

}
```

Comment: OK, what's your actual question? What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: A hint: A pair of braces is like a closed room. Any declared variable within that scope (*room*) is not visible outside.

Comment: i want to convert minutes and seconds (UItextField) into int variable so i can do operation with them in func timerRunning

Comment: @vadian i want to put minutes and seconds into an int variable, i tried declaring the var outside of function but XCode says it cannot be use instance members within property initializer

Comment: Actually you don't need the variables `min` and `sec` at all. In `btn_Timer` only start or stop the timer. In `timerRunning()` get the values of the labels, convert them to `Int`, decrease them, convert them back to `String` and reassign them to the labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vadian pointed out in the comments, you need to declare `min` and `sec` as properties so that they can be accessed from the `timerRunning` method.

Also, I suggest you make use of the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to safely unwrap the `UITextField` `text` values and the result of the `Int` conversion.

```
@IBOutlet weak var minutes: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var seconds: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var label_Timer: UILabel!

var min = 0
var sec = 0

@IBAction func btn_Timer(_ sender: UITextField) {

    min = Int(minutes.text ?? "") ?? 0
    sec = Int(seconds.text ?? "") ?? 0

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerRunning), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func timerRunning(){

    sec -= 1

    //operate on min and sec here

}
```